# php mysql, how to add multiple images for single event id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a report management website.

My question is: how to add more than one image for that report in database. For example if a report has id=1 how can we add 5 images for that event.

Comment: If you are storing path of image in database then you can store each path with comma seperated or any separator which you like more.

Comment: no, i'm storing image with type blob

Comment: "no, i'm storing image with type blob "  well don't

Comment: search for should i save images in the database

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: Create a table where you store the report id and the image. You will have the same report id multiple time, one for each image. Then with a join on report id you will fetch the information back

Comment: work fine thanx. Lelio Faieta

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php 
$image1="test1.jpej"; // or $image1="www.ex.com/test1.jpej";
$image2="test2.jpej";
$image3="test3.jpej";
$image4="test4.jpej";
$image5="test5.jpej";  
 $img=serialize(array($image1,$image2,$image3,$image4,$image5));
?>
```

$img variable stoe the database column

and get the data in the database the varible is unserialize

```
<?php 
   $images= unserialize($img);
   print_r($images);
?>
```

Comment: OP is storing the images as BLOB, not as urls.